# Which Cypress chainer should I use to test an alias was called with matching arguments

Tags: cypress, sinon-chai

I am using Cypress to do E2E tests. I am using the Sinon.Chai chainer `be.calledWithMatch` to test that an alias was called with matching arguments:

```js
cy.get('@myAlias')
  .should('be.calledWithMatch', {
    param: 'value',
    otherParam: 'other value'
  });
```

The assertion works as expected, but provides the following non-explicit error message:

```
expected myAlias to have been called with arguments matching Object{2}
```

What I would like is to use a chainer allowing me to:

- Test something was called with matching arguments (just like `be.calledWithMatch`)
- Provide an explicit assertion message that shows the expected values. For example:

```
expected myAlias to have been called with arguments matching { param: 'value', otherParam: 'other value' }
```

I thought of using a combination of `.wrap()`, `.find()` and `.should('eq')`, but that would be much complex. Is there a more appropriate chainer to achieve what I expect?